# Getting error in sqlite like query in ionic1

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using sqlite select query to retrieve the name from a list in which I have used the following select query with like but it gives me an error as NaN can anyone tell me what's wrong in this query.

```
var query = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ' + tblName + ' WHERE name LIKE ' % '' + name + '' % ' ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC';
```

Error:

> getAllSearchQuery:  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM phonebookNaNViNaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ' + tblName + ' WHERE name LIKE \'%' + name + '%\' ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC';
```

because name is string, so need add ' or ", if your code is using ', so you need add a slash (\)

Comment: Getting error as Object {message: "sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: near "%": syntax error", code: 5}  and the log is SELECT DISTINCT * FROM phonebook WHERE name LIKE %Vishnu% ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE

Comment: `var query = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ' + tblName + ' WHERE name LIKE \'%' + name + '%\' ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC';`
or this code
`var query = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ' + tblName + ' WHERE name LIKE "%' + name + '%" ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC';`

Sorry, that's my wrong, because name is string, so need add ' or ", because your code is using ', so you need add a slash to \ for it

Comment: please tick and +1 if my answer is useful. Thanks you.

Comment: can u update ur answer with this following code which u have given so that i can make it to be correct.var query = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ' + tblName + ' WHERE name LIKE \'%' + name + '%\' ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC';

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is with quotes absence. Try to use the combination of ' and " if it's possible in the programming language you use, something like this would probably work:

```
var query = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ' + tblName + ' WHERE name LIKE "%' + name + '%" ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC';
```

or reverse:

```
var query = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ' + tblName + ' WHERE name LIKE '%" + name + "%' ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC';
```

The point in combination of quotes is that this allows to include one quoted part of code into another.